# too old to migrate close dialog text

Tags: feature-request, design, close-reasons, migration

I think this *(too old to migrate)* must of just been added since don't remember seeing it before:

[image]

That's some good information to know, however, I don't think this message should appear next to the *off-topic because...* input since there are 7 off-topic reasons (6 without the migrate option).

Currently if the question is too old, the off-topic dialog just doesn't even show the migrate option. I would request that instead of just not showing it that we disable that input, grey it out, and add the *(too old to migrate)* message at the end of it. And then remove the *(too old to migrate)* that's next to the *off-topic because...*

[image]

Comment: It existed before, there was just a [long-standing bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/248253) that was preventing it being displayed. ;) We complained enough to get it fixed apparently.